# Is there any way to limit ath9k wifi device to 1m - 2m bitrate when using WPA? (DBPSK & DQPSK)

Tags: linux, wifi

This used to be as simple as running

```
iwconfig wlan0 rate 2M auto
```

but this clearly does not work despite running without error. I also tried

```
iw wlan0 set bitrates legacy-2.4 1 2
```

to no avail. Is there some secret sauce to limiting the modulations used by the ath9k driver or is something in Linux just plain broken?